# How to display grid view in unbercart catalog

Tags: drupal, gridview, drupal-7, grid, ubercart

I am new to `Drupal` and `ubercart`, Actually making my first site on `Drupal CMS`.

I am developing online store with the help of ubercart. I am getting difficulties to display products in grid view for catalog.

As long as I understand correctly, we can create product categories from
**Texonomy->add term**

when I open url for example, http://[Website_URL]?q=[catalog_term_name]

I end up with the page where products are listed in list form not as Grid.

I am using `drupal 7` and `ubercarts's` latest version[just downloaded two days ago], and as
long as I know ubercart supports grid view but how to display it.... I dont know.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin > structure > views ( For Drupal 7.x) and customize t he catalog view.

Comment: Thanks. I found out after a long exercise.

Comment: You know what does it mean? Hover your mouse over there and you know it! Make sure you know what you write before accusing!